# Sorting HQL join path errors

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hql

I am having trouble translating a mildly complex (~8 sloc) SQL query to the HQL language.

I have been messing around with it for a day, sadly, the examples on the internet are way too trivial to be any help. I have reduced my query to the smallest sample that still gives the path error. Any clues would be appreciated.

SQL (works)

```
SELECT container_modulelist 
FROM project.t_type 
INNER JOIN project.t_module ON project.t_type.module_id =project.t_module.id 
WHERE project.t_type.id = 111
```

HQL (gives join path error)

```
    @Query("
select module.container_modulelist 
from Type type 
join Module module on type.module_id = module.id 
where type.id =111
")
```

Update : the above part should be solved by answer below

However, I still have a problem getting the sub query to execute.

I tested the section outside the brackets and it works great. However I am having trouble implementing the part in the brackets(from the answer below), I'd like to evaluate the sub query and compare it in order for my query to return the value, I have seen this can be done from the HQL documentation. In the current form, the sub query doesn't return with anything no matter the parameter.

Equivalent(?) HQL (sub query not working):

```
@Query("
        select value from Value value
            where value.type.module.containerModuleList = (
                select type.module.containerModuleList from Type type 
                    where type.id =111) and value.name =yyy5
")
Value findOneByNameFromModuleList(@Param("id") Long id, @Param("name") String name);
```

Working part:

```
 @Query("
         select value from Value value
             where value.type.module.containerModuleList = 1 and value.name =yyy5
 ")
 Value findOneByNameFromModuleList(@Param("name") String name);
```

Comment: Got it. I was missing an annotation in my resource class. So my queries didn't  return anything found when I had both params enabled. Had:

    `public Boolean isValueNameTaken(@PathVariable final Long id, final String name)` 
 Instead of:

    `public Boolean isValueNameTaken(@PathVariable final Long id,     @PathVariable final String name)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HQL doesn't use table and column names, but entity and field/property names. You idn't post your entities, so it's hard to answer. But your query seems to use column names, or your Java code doesn't respect Java conventions at all.

Furthermore, you don't need any `on` clause on joins, because you use associations between entities for joins, and since these associations are already mapped with JoinTable/JoinColumn, Hibernate knows how the tables must be joined.

So, assuming your entities respect the Java naming conventions, and that you have a ManyToOne association between the `Type` and `Module` entities (i.e. there is a field `module` of type `Module` annotated with `@ManyToOne` in `Type`), the query should be

```
select cml
from Type type 
join type.module module
join module.containerModuleList cml
where type.id = 111
```

Or simply

```
select type.module.containerModuleList from Type type where type.id = 111
```

[This is documented](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html#queryhql-joins).

Comment: Yes, they do respect conventions, I was trying to simplify it. 
`@JoinColumn(name = "container_modulelist", nullable = false)
    private ModuleList containerModuleList;`
Is what I have there. 
I am getting another error now, 
`Invalid path: module.containerModuleList' `
maybe because there is no Module alias keyword here?

Comment: Ah, so containerModuleList is another association. I've edited the query.

Comment: Thank you I figured it out with this help!